# How do I make a drive write-protected/read-only in linux?

Tags: linux, hard-drive

I have installed Ubuntu on my machine, I have Windows on a small ssd and I would like that ssd not visible or read-only while I am using linux as I do not want any mistakes to mess up that drive...

Comment: What you're looking to do is make the windows partition write-protected or *read only*. Try searching ubuntu forums for those terms and see where that gets you. Alternatively, take a look over at [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/101637/usb-turn-write-protection-off)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mount the disk, it won't be visible from the Linux file system.

The file /etc/fstab is where your systems knows what volume to mount, so if your drive is not in here, it will not be mounted.

If your disk is mounted at the moment, you can use mount to find where it is mounted and what is it's dev file location (it is going to be something like /dev/sda or /dev/dsb). You can then go to the /etc/fstab file and remove the line mentioning it so it is not mounted at next boot time.

Answer (score 0):

Note that just not mounting is *not* enough. There's still the device file in `/dev/sd*` and the root user can certainly write to that file, no matter what its permissions are. The only guarantee to prevent foot-shooting is to **disconnect** the drive power or data cable. This is easier than it sounds with pluggable hard disk drive racks or externally pluggable drive bays.